# Upload multiple dictionaries on s3 by having each dictionary in separate line

Tags: python, amazon-s3

Recently I started working with s3 and I've stumbled upon an issue. I insert objects into s3 by running

```
s3.put_object(
    Body=json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False),
    Bucket=bucket_name,
    Key=key,
    ContentType='application/json; charset=utf-8',
)
```

where `data` is of type `dict` in Python. For example, `data` might be `{"key1":"val1", "key2":"val2"}`. When I upload it now, it works pretty well and if I download the file from s3, it has a json structure as expected. However, now I want to upload multiple dicts into one json file but I want to have those dicts in separate line, is this possible? For example, when I download the file, I'd like to have my file like

```
{"key1":"val1", "key2":"val2"}
{"key3":"val3", "key4":"val4"}
```

Comment: `Body='\n'.join(json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False) for data in data_list)`?

Comment: But this is not correct json structure it can be list of dict. You are storing it as json but want all dictionary in separate line . Since your ContentType is application/json

Comment: Oh right, what should I set that to? @DeepakTripathi.

Comment: @anthino12 Try with `application/jsonlines` and if it doesn't work, `text/plain` should do (combined with the `Body` suggested by Max)